# Publishing to Google pubsub as a JSON through an http request

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I was trying to push some data to PUB/SUB as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#pubsub-publish-message-protocol)

I assume, the URL "POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-id/topics/mytopic-name:publish" with needed data in a json format as described , would publish the data to the pubsub. Is my assumption correct here? or should I write my own handler to publish the data which i get from a webpage using java/php/python etc?

I could successfully push the data through google play ground. But this requires my username/password to be given to authenticate.

Can I use API_KEY alone here to send the data from my webpage to google pubsub? Or should I go for OAuth2.0 login? If OAuth is used, is there any way to provide the client_id and the API_KEY to do the authentication without prompting the user to enter credentials?

Any help on the above topics would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, it is more advisable to us a service account when using Google Cloud  Platform. There are limited cases that API keys are more appropriate than [using the standard authentication flow instead](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys).

Comment: There is also a [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform) provided by Google about "Authenticating to Cloud Platform with Service Accounts" this will greatly help since it talks about authenticating with service account and from creating a Pub/Sub topic to test receiving Pub/Sub messages. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rebot. I have tried out a few options. Let me go through the topics you shared and will get back. Cheers.!

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using one of the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) with a service account. This will make authentication straightforward, by setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.  If you cannot do this for some reason, you can set the Authorization: Bearer header with an OAuth token as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish?apix=true).